# How do I force a value to be unique in 2 columns in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have a table:

```
table: {
    category,
    col1,
    col2
}
```

I want the values of `col1` and `col2` to be unique as per the value of `category`.

For example,

```
category | col1 | col2
1        | 1    | 2
2        | 1    | 2
```

would be allowed, while

```
category | col1 | col2
1        | 1    | 2
1        | 3    | 1
```

would not because the value `1` is duplicated for category `1`.
Is it possible to to configure a unique index or other constraint in MySQL to force such a rule?

Comment: You can create a multi-column unique index for that, but beware for possible performance penalties.

Comment: With your example it is not getting clear  `category` column unique on it's own i.e. will values, `1,1,1` and `1,2,2` will be allowed or not. You need uniqueness on all three columns. add more explanation

Comment: the category column is in itself not unique.
It's Ok to disallow `1, 1, 1` or `1, 2, 2`